# Is can use google Native Client to Achieve screenshots?

Tags: google-nativeclient

chrome 42 not support npapi,so i want use nativeclient(ppapi) to Achieve screenshots?
but how to do use c++ ? or , is can to Achieve screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`captureVisibleTab` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab). This API doesn't seem available through Pepper but is available through JavaScript. You can communicate between the two if that's necessary.

Comment: thanks,but that in JavaScript is too weak and can't cross window